# Gaining Access to a File in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, ipad, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to print a file from a filepath but first I need to request access to the file using `StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource`.

At the moment I've got the following code:

```
       private void Initialise_Print()
    {
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString("file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Code/Documents/Test.pdf");
            var securityEnabled = url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

            PrintDoc(url.Path);
    }
```

But `StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource` always returns false, denying me access and causing the printer to be unable to find the file, why is this?

Also, passing the `NSUrl` in from a file picker works but not when created from a filepath.

Comment: Does the app need to save files or just access them? Also, can you leverage a lib for perms like [plugin.permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/plugin.permissions)

Comment: It just needs to access them to print them - no need to save them.
I'll look into the permissions library, thanks.

Comment: You can not access it if the pdf in another app's sandbox.